# Understanding the proof of the Brezis-Lieb lemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of the Brezis-Lieb lemma from the Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brezis%E2%80%93Lieb_lemma

Here is the statement of said lemma:
Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of measurable complex-valued functions on $X$ which converge almost everywhere to a function $f$. The limiting function $f$ is automatically measurable. The Brezis–Lieb lemma asserts that if $p$ is a positive number, then
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\int _{X}{\Big |}|f|^{p}-|f_{n}|^{p}+|f-f_{n}|^{p}{\Big |}\,d\mu =0$$
provided that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^p(X, \mu)$.

[image]

So I am uncertain about this last line of this proof. Specifically, why is the supremum finite? This is essentially saying that for all $n$, the integral is finite correct? But that would imply that $f-f_n$ is in $L^p$ which would imply $f$ is in $L^p$ which is not true in general since all we know is that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You omitted the most important hypothesis! The $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are bounded in $L^p(\mu)$; let’s call this uniform bound $M$. Since $f_n\to f$ pointwise, we can apply Fatou’s lemma to get
\begin{align}
\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu&\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n|^p\,d\mu\leq M<\infty,
\end{align}
so $f\in L^p(\mu)$.

With this, the supremum in question is indeed finite because
\begin{align}
\int_X|f-f_n|^p\,d\mu&\leq\int_XB_p(|f|^p+|f_n|^p)\,d\mu\leq 2BM,
\end{align}
where the constant $B_p$ is independent of $n$ (probably $2^p$ works). Alternatively, you could just use the triangle inequality in $L^p$: $\|f-f_n\|_p\leq\|f\|_p+\|f_n\|_p\leq \|f\|_p+M$, so its $p^{th}$ power is also finite, just as we see above.